# Openlayers minZoom and maxResolution is not working

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I got a very basic code. I can not manage to arrange minZoom of "mahalle" layer. I want it to be visible after 5-6 zoom levels. I can also use maxResolution but it is not working either.

Strange part is maxZoom or minResolution is working! If I add "minResolution: 4000" or "maxZoom: 6" it is working but in a opposite way. So when i open the map i see the layer and when I zoom in after 4-5 zooms, it disappears but i want to do the opposite way, it should appear after 5-6 zoom levels.

Here it is my code:

```
import 'ol/ol.css';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import OSM from 'ol/source/OSM';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import View from 'ol/View';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import GeoJSON from "ol/format/GeoJSON";
import {bbox} from 'ol/loadingstrategy';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
import {Fill, Stroke, Style, Text} from 'ol/style';

var style = new Style({
  fill: new Fill({
    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6)',
  }),
  stroke: new Stroke({
    color: '#319FD3',
    width: 1,
  }),
  text: new Text({
    font: '12px Calibri,sans-serif',
    fill: new Fill({
      color: '#000',
    }),
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: '#fff',
      width: 3,
    }),
  }),
});

const vectorSource = (layer) => {
  return new VectorSource({
    format: new GeoJSON(),
    url: (extent) => {
      return (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bugra/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Bugra:${layer}&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=${extent.join(',')}`);
    },
    strategy: bbox,
  })
};

// Layer creating class
const mahalle = new VectorLayer({
  source: vectorSource("ABS_MAHALLE_M"),
  style: function (feature) {
    style.getText().setText(feature.get('adi'));
    return style;
  },
  // These are working separately but in the opposite way
  // maxZoom: 6,
  // minResolution: 4000,

  // This is the way i want to apply but not working
  // maxResolution: 4000,
  // minZoom: 6
});

var map = new Map({
  target: 'map',
  layers: [
    new TileLayer({
      maxZoom: 20, // visible at zoom levels 14 and below
      source: new OSM(),
    }),
    mahalle
  ],
  view: new View({
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 1
  }),
});

map.getView().on("change", function() {
  console.log(map.getView().getResolution());
  console.log(mahalle.getMaxResolution())
});
```

Comment: It works as expected here https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-haze-obx5i?file=/main.js The view opens at zoom 10 and with minZoom set to 11.9 the vector features appear at level 12 (note that minZoom and maxResolution are exclusive, if set to 12 the feature would not be seen at level 12).

Comment: Thanks Mike! With your clear example i found the piece i forgot. For anyone having the same problem I forgot to add this ",EPSG:3857" code after my geoserver URL. So here is the correct code:

const vectorSource = (layer) => {
  return new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: (extent) => {
      return (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bugra/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Bugra:${layer}&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=${extent.join(',')},EPSG:3857`);
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
  })
};

Answer (score 1):

Actually Mike found the solution.

Thanks Mike! With your clear example i found the piece i forgot. For anyone having the same problem I forgot to add this **",EPSG:3857"** code after my geoserver URL. So here is the correct code:

```
const vectorSource = (layer) => {
  return new ol.source.Vector({
    format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
    url: (extent) => {
      return (`http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Bugra/ows? service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=Bugra:${layer}&outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&bbox=${extent.join(',')},EPSG:3857`);
    },
    strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.bbox,
  })
};
```

After that, now I can use minZoom: XXXX code perfectly!